# initializing static values in C++ classes equal to each-other

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

class a {
 public:
 static int num;
};

class b {
 public:
 static int num;
};

int a::num = b::num;

int b::num = 6;

int main(){
 std::cout << a::num << std::endl;
 return 0;
}
```

The above prints `6`.

My question is, how it that possible since when doing `a::num = b::num`, `b::num` doesn't have a value yet.

Comment: Oh, it has a value, but it could be anything. Hopefully the compiler gives a warning on using uninitialized variables. Turn on warnings. Although, being static, they could be initialized in any order.

Comment: just to be sure, is the question why you get `6` or how to initialize both with `6` in a less obscure way? or perhaps both?

Comment: There's no guarantee on the initialization order of statics. Suggested reading: static initialization order fiasco.

Comment: Recommended reading: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub , https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order

Comment: @Macmade There actually is a guarantee in this specific case: see [Andrey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60173618/459640). But yes, this sort of thing is dangerous more generally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're seeing interaction of different [initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization) stages in this example. The initialization happens in this order:

1. Static initialization stage.

   - `a::num` is [zero-initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization) as a static non-local variable.
   - `b::num` is initialized during the [constant initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_initialization) stage because its initializer is a constant expression `6`.
2. Dynamic initialization stage.

   - `a::num` is initialized from expression `b::num`, which is not a [constant expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression). At this point `b::num` is already initialized to 6.

Note that the compiler is allowed to initialize `a::num` statically, if it can maintain the same effect as the above sequence.

Answer (score 0):

For static variables, the initialization order is not necessarily the order of instructions. Take a look at the debugger result: The variable **b::num** is already initialized while the debugger points to the previous instruction!

[image]